# Unity Smooth 2D Camera following - Huge Issue :(

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, smoothing

As you can see in the topic - I have a camera problem. I use a script (you can see below) and I have something like this - http://rapidgamesstudio.com/games/diggermachines/

What I want to achieve is a smooth following camera to player.
I've tried everything. I have about 50-60 fps and still this bug occures.

This is my camera code:

```
void Update() {

if(!player)
    return;

//if(!isDiggableCamera) {
    Vector3 point = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(player.transform.position);
    Vector3 delta = player.transform.position - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, point.z)); //(new Vector3(0.5, 0.5, point.z));
    Vector3 destination = transform.position + delta;
    destination.z = transform.position.z;
    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, destination, ref velocity, dampTime);

//Vector3 destination = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, player.transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
//transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, destination, ref velocity, dampTime);

//} else {
//    startDigging(0, 0, 0);
//}

leftSite.position = new Vector3(leftSite.position.x, player.position.y, leftSite.position.z);
rightSite.position = new Vector3(rightSite.position.x, 

player.position.y, rightSite.position.z);
}
```

I tried execute this code in Update(), FixedUpdate(), LateUpdate() even with all three - and still is the same problem.

Below code for updating player position:

```
//move player

float changableSpeedX = 5000.0f;
        float changableSpeedY = 6000.0f;
        Vector2 speed = new Vector2(x * Time.deltaTime * changableSpeedX,
                                    y * Time.deltaTime * changableSpeedY);


        //if(playerRigidbody.velocity.y + speed.y >= Game.game().activeMaxVelY)
        //    speed.y = Game.game().activeMaxVelY - playerRigidbody.velocity.y;

        playerRigidbody.AddForce(speed);
            //AddForce(speed);


//and checking max speed

protected void checkSpeed()
    {
        if(playerRigidbody.velocity.x > Game.game().activeMaxVelX)
            playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(Game.game().activeMaxVelX, playerRigidbody.velocity.y);

        if(playerRigidbody.velocity.x < -Game.game().activeMaxVelX)
            playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(-Game.game().activeMaxVelX, playerRigidbody.velocity.y);


        if(playerRigidbody.velocity.y > Game.game().activeMaxVelY)
            playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody.velocity.x, Game.game().activeMaxVelY);

        if(playerRigidbody.velocity.y < maxSpeedYGravity)
            playerRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(playerRigidbody.velocity.x, maxSpeedYGravity);
    }
```

Could anyone help me?

If you need more code please let me know which part (because I don't want to add too much unnecessary code)

Comment: I am very sorry, i want to help but i cannot access the web player atm (company rules), can you please just give me a small idea of what is happening?

Comment: The problem is with camera following to player. Everything jumping instead of being smoothly. I tried "Interpolation" but still is the same problem. Other guys told me that something maybe wrong with moving object in "Update()" but in FixedUpdate() is the same...

Comment: Well, later i'll see the game, but the reason might be that, in your code logic, the transition of the camera is made by calculating a certain speed, and since the velocity of the object varies in one update, you only get that update on the following frame and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Might i suggest a lerp sir , in the update function use this

```
  maincamera.transform.position = new vector3(maincamera.transform.position,player.transform.poistion,speed*Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This One !!!

```
 private float xMax;
[SerializeField]
private float yMax;
[SerializeField]
private float xMin;
[SerializeField] 
private float yMin;
private Transform target;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    target = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () {
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(target.position.x, xMin, xMax), Mathf.Clamp(target.position.y, yMin, yMax),transform.position.z);
}
```

}